# Is forcing action on spark dataframe required?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this below code snippet, which is working fine.

So here are 2 actions in the code. `updateDF.first()` and `mergedDF.save()`
`updateDF.count()` which is a dummy action, if I remove it job is failing. Is it necessary to force such kind of action in the code. I am feeling if I remove `updateDF.count()`, it will first encounter action on `mergedDF.save()`. And when it compute `mergedDF.save()` it creates more intermediary dataframes which causing the job to be failed. Could you suggest any code change to make it better.

```
newDataDF.persist()
val historyDataDF=hiveContext.read.format("orc").load(stagingFullPath).persist()

val updateDF = historyDataDF.coalesce(5).join(newDataDF, jobPrimaryKey).select(historyDataDF.columns.map(historyDataDF(_)): _*).persist()

println(updateDF.count())

val unchangedDF = historyDataDF.except(updateDF).persist()

val mergedDF = unchangedDF.unionAll(newDataDF).persist()
mergedDF.write.format("orc").mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite).save(stagingFullPath)
```

Comment: what's the failure? Can you add the exception / error message?

Comment: why do you persist each df? you should only persist if you intend on using this data frame for multiple calculation. also persist is performed lazily so be careful when using unpersist (I don't see it here but maybe you have it later on and this could cause errors and I suspect it is the case here).
coalesce(5) is very costly... why do you use it and why there?
select(historyDataDF.columns.map(historyDataDF(_)): _*) - what are you trying to do here?